# How to pass multiple model as parameter in WEB API

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, postman, webapi

Can anyone please help me to pass multiple models as a parameter to the request's content in WEB API?

I have 2 different Model Student and Employee

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
```

I have created an API and want to pass both these models as parameters in my action method **InsertTestAPI**.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("TestAPI")]

public HttpResponseMessage InsertTestAPI(Student modelStudent, Employee modelEmployee)
{
    // other logical operations
}
```

When I pass these models as JSON in the request body, I get the following error from Postman.

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Can't bind multiple parameters ('modelStudent' and 'modelEmployee') to the request's content.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()"
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StudentEmployeModel
{
 public Student Students{get;set;}


public Employee Employees{get;set;}
}
```

Create the StudentEmpendedModel class this way.

```
public HttpResponseMessage InsertTestAPI(StudentEmployeModel model)
{// other logical operations }
```

request this way

```
    { "students":   { "studentId":"0", "studentName":"Mehmet", "branch":"software" } ,
 "employees":
 {"employeeId ":0,"employeeName":"Test","department":"IT"} }
```

This way you can send requests as Json

Comment: Hi Mehmet, Thank you for your valuable response, can you please let me know how can I set value in the Students and Employees model while I pass StudentEmployeModel as JSON in the request body?

Comment: I wrote the answer in the comment

Answer (score 1):

You can call Empolyee class in student class after that .then you can call multiple model call in api

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
        public Employee EmpData {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Divyanshi for your valuable answer, your solution is also working but I can accept the answer for all so I upvoted your answer also. Thank you.